# Can if-clause be used as a loop? (DataStructure, C Language)

Tags: c, if-statement, data-structures

I'm learning the DataStructure on binary search tree part. I'm trying to print the binary tree in an inorder traversal way. On my textbook, it uses if clause to implement it. But if-clause isn't a loop.. How does it work? Is it related to using pointer root?

Also, I don't understand how the function calls itself and still works.

```
void displayInorder (treeNode *root){
    if(root) {
        displayInorder(root->left);
        printf("%c", root->key);
        displayInorder(root->right);
    }
```

Also, when I called it on main function, I used it like this.

> displayInorder(root);

And it works just fine!
But I just don't understand the process.

Comment: Look up "recursive function" and "recursion", and learn what they mean and how they're used.  Basically a function can call itself to solve a smaller problem, then use the result of that call to solve a larger one.

Comment: If the book does not explain recursion in the text somewhere around that function, it's not a very good book.

Comment: There really isn't a clear question being asked here.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

The function isn't using a loop to display a binary tree. It is using recursion. You are calling the same function "displayInorder" from inside the function.